Can anyone explain me eav_entity_type table its fields uses
I was going through the table and was curious what is the use of some of the fields.

In Magento 2, the eav_entity_type table is a key component of the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model, which provides a flexible way to manage entities such as products, categories, and customers. Here’s a detailed overview of its fields and their purposes:
Fields in the eav_entity_type Table

entity_type_id

Type: int
Description: This is the primary key of the table, uniquely identifying each entity type. It is used to link to other EAV-related tables.


entity_type_code

Type: varchar
Description: A unique code for the entity type (e.g., 'catalog_product', 'customer', 'catalog_category'). It is used in code and admin interfaces to refer to specific entity types.


attribute_model

Type: varchar
Description: Specifies the model class used for attribute-related operations. This field is often null if no custom attribute model is used.


entity_table

Type: varchar
Description: The name of the table where the base entity data is stored, such as catalog_product_entity for products.


value_table_prefix

Type: varchar
Description: A prefix used to generate the table names where entity attribute values are stored. It helps in creating tables like catalog_product_entity_varchar.


entity_id_field

Type: varchar
Description: Defines the name of the primary key field for the entity records, typically entity_id.


increment_model

Type: varchar
Description: Specifies the model for managing incrementing entity IDs, crucial for entities like orders that require sequential IDs.


increment_per_store

Type: int
Description: Indicates if increment IDs should be unique per store view (1 for true, 0 for false). Relevant for entities needing unique IDs across different store views.


parent_id_field

Type: varchar
Description: Defines the field name in the table that holds the parent entity ID, used in hierarchical entities.


is_data_shared

Type: int
Description: Indicates whether entity data is shared across store views (1 for shared, 0 for not shared).



Usage

Entity Identification: The entity_type_id is essential for identifying specific entity types and linking with related tables.

Attribute Management: The entity_table field contains the main data for the entity type, while the value_table_prefix helps locate tables storing attribute values.

Custom Models: Fields like attribute_model and increment_model are used for custom implementations when necessary.

Data Sharing: The is_data_shared field helps determine if entity data should be shared across different store views.


In summary, the eav_entity_type table plays a crucial role in managing various entity types and their attributes in Magento 2, facilitating a flexible and efficient data handling system.
